# How to unzip files from multiple directories at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, zip

I have 13 directories, each directory contains around 30 zipped files which are quiet big. With below code I'm creating a counterpart of the directories, unzipping the files and renaming them. Now I have one big problem, its working to slow. Doing all above for each directory takes about 6 or 7 minutes, so for all the directories I need approximately 7 x 13 = 91 minutes.

Are there options to make this faster? If the software could run the 13 directories parallelly then it would probably just take about 7 minutes for 13 directories. I've read about multiprocessing but I don't know how to implement it in my current code.

**This is my code:**

```
pattern = '*.zip'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data_files): 
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern): 

        path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        date_zipped_file_s = re.search('-(.\d+)-', filename).group(1)
        date_zipped_file = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_zipped_file_s, '%Y%m%d').date()      
              
        #Create the new directory location
        new_dir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.relpath(path, start=data_files), ".."))

        #Join the directory names counter_part and create their paths.
        new = os.path.join(counter_part, new_dir)

        #Create the directories
        if (not os.path.exists(new)):
            os.makedirs(new)
        zipfile.ZipFile(path).extractall(new) 
    
        #Get al the zipped files
        files = os.listdir(new)
    
        #Rename all the files in the created directories
        for file in files:
            filesplit = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))
            if not re.search(r'_\d{8}.', file):
                os.rename(os.path.join(new, file), os.path.join(new, filesplit[0]+'_'+date_zipped_file_s+filesplit[1]))
```

Comment: This is not a [minimal , reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, `counter_part` is not defined (and, of course, you are missing import statements).

Comment: @Booboo `counter_part` is just a path where the zipped + renamed files will be stored

Comment: That is obvious, but if the code is to be restructured for multiprocessing, I would need to know where it comes from.

Comment: @Booboo can we have a private chat somewhere so I can give you a detailed explanation? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think that will be necessary; I will post something and you can restructure it as you see fit.

Comment: Oke thank you I will take a look at it. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not expect to see a reduction running time by a factor of 13 by using multiprocessing. For that to occur, you would probably need a computer with (1) at least 13 physical cores that were not running any other processes and (2) some type of solid state drive that could handle at least 13 multiple I/O requests in parallel without any noticeable deterioration in any request's response time.

How much improvement, if any, will you get? There is only one way of finding out. The following code processes all the input zip file names and creates 13 lists of (root, filename) tuples where each list has a single root value that is distinct from all the other lists. A multiprocessing pool of size 13 is created and each process in the pool is assigned one of these 13 lists to process.

You will need to update the definitions of `data_files` and `counter_part` in  the code below:

```py
import os
import fnmatch
import zipfile
import re
import datetime
from multiprocessing import Pool

def generate_file_lists():
    # Change the following line to a real path
    data_files = '?'
    pattern = '*.zip'
    last_root = None
    args = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data_files):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            if root != last_root:
                last_root = root
                if args:
                    yield args
                    args = []
            args.append((root, filename))
    if args:
        yield args

def unzip(file_list):
    """
    file_list is a list of (root, filename) tuples where
    root is the same for all tuples.
    """
    # Change the following line to a real path:
    counter_part = '?'
    for root, filename in file_list:
        path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        date_zipped_file_s = re.search('-(.\d+)-', filename).group(1)
        date_zipped_file = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_zipped_file_s, '%Y%m%d').date()

        #Create the new directory location
        new_dir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.relpath(path, start=data_files), ".."))

        #Join the directory names counter_part and create their paths.
        new = os.path.join(counter_part, new_dir)

        #Create the directories
        if (not os.path.exists(new)):
            os.makedirs(new)
        zipfile.ZipFile(path).extractall(new)

        #Get al the zipped files
        files = os.listdir(new)

        #Rename all the files in the created directories
        for file in files:
            filesplit = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))
            if not re.search(r'_\d{8}.', file):
                os.rename(os.path.join(new, file), os.path.join(new, filesplit[0]+'_'+date_zipped_file_s+filesplit[1]))

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(13)
    pool.map(unzip, generate_file_lists())
```

Comment: And what type of improvement did you see?

Comment: its going way faster. But I need you to explain me what is it exactly doing? I really need to understand it.

Comment: The second paragraph of my answer explains precisely what the code is doing. Are you having difficulty in matching up that description with the actual code. I mean, what precisely don't you understand?

Comment: Im trying to understand the generate_file_list part. What is the last_root doing and the yargs? Can you explan that further?

Comment: Also, is this multiprocessing running things parallelly or what because the running time is at least 10X faster right now. In aprox 3 or 4 minutes all the files where processed and unzipped?

Comment: Are you familiar with generator functions? And, yes, everything is running in parallel.

Comment: Yes I heard of it.

Comment: Hearing about it is one thing. I am sure if you now go back and read all about them you will have a better understanding.

Comment: Okay I will do that. By the way, after impleneting your code in part of my software I got this error: `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\data\\Anjako\\Desktop\\proces_1\\\Fuertaleza\\FFAD01.txt'
    shutil.rmtree(file_path)`

Comment: First, I suggest you download the Python 3 Cookbook from [here](https://github.com/lpvcpp/learn_python/blob/master/D.%20Beazley%2C%20B.K.%20Jones%20-%20Python%20Cookbook%2C%203rd%20Edition.%202013.pdf) and study Chapter 4 (but the whole book is fabulous). Second, nowhere in the code that I posted do I call `shutil.rmtree`. ??????

Comment: I said I implemented your code in an other piece of code. After I unzip the files I start processing them which is done by an other snippet.

Comment: You should post a *new question* with that snippet. I don't know what `file_path` is and how it relates to anything to what has been posted (please *don't* tell me). Piggybacking new questions on already-answered questions is very much to be avoided.

Comment: But it sounds like you have left open one of the files you are trying to delete.